# Cannot create virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am trying to create a virtual environ on a linux server. But I get the following error:

```
$ virtualenv venv2
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2
New python executable in /home/org/cpmf2-biotec/apps/venv2/bin/python2
Also creating executable in /home/org/cpmf2-biotec/apps/venv2/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...
Complete output from command /home/org/cpmf2-biotec/apps/venv2/bin/python2 - setuptools pkg_resources pip wheel:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 24, in <module>
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__init__.py", line 215, in main
File "/home/org/cpmf2-biotec/apps/venv2/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 581, in setlocale
   return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2363, in <module>
main()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 719, in main
symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 988, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 918, in install_wheel
call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 812, in call_subprocess
% (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /home/org/cpmf2-biotec/apps/venv2/bin/python2 - setuptools pkg_resources pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

I have no idea what this means. Can someone tell me how I could fix this?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

I've had this problem once. Setting the locale to default seemed to help me.

Run

```
export LC_ALL="C"
```

and then try creating the virtual environment.